# Issue when showing associativity property of Banach algebra $(L^1(\mathbb{R}^n), \ast)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I'm trying to show $(L^1(\mathbb{R}^n), \ast)$ is a Banach algebra and I'm ending up with some variables in switched positions.

Let $f, g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and define the convolution of $f$ with $g$ by
$$
(f \ast g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)g(x-y)dy.
$$
Now $(L^1(\mathbb{R}^n), \ast)$ is a Banach algebra. I am trying to show this by showing that for $a,b,c \in (L^1(\mathbb{R}^n), \ast)$ we have the associative property $(a\ast b) \ast c = a \ast (b \ast c)$.

First we have
\begin{align}
((a\ast b) \ast c) (x) & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (a\ast b)(y)c(x-y)dy \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}a(z)\mathbf{b(y-z)}dz \ c(x-y)dy,
\end{align}
and I have bolded the term that I will have an issue with later.

And then
\begin{align}
(a \ast (b \ast c)) (x) & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} a(y)(b\ast c)(x-y)dy \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} a(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}b(z)c(x-y-z)dzdy \\
\end{align}
Making the change of variables $\phi = y-z$ we have $z = y - \phi, \ d\phi = - dz$ and then
\begin{align}
(a \ast (b \ast c)) (x) & = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} a(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}b(y-\phi)c(x-\phi)d\phi dy \\
& = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} a(y)b(y-\phi)dy \ c(x-\phi)d\phi \\
\end{align}
Now replacing $y$ with $z$ and $\phi$ with $y$ I have
$$
(a \ast (b \ast c)) (x) = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} a(z)\mathbf{b(z-y)}dy \ c(x-y)dy,
$$
and I have bolded the term corresponding to the one I bolded earlier. The function $b$ has the variables switched in the last expression compared to the earlier one, and there is also a minus sign in the final expression. I don't know whether it's possible to 'bring the minus sign into b' in the final expression? Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $c (x-y-z) = c (x- (y+z)) $ in one of the integrals and then substitute $\phi = y-z $ to get $c (x-\phi) $. This is incorrect, you should have used $\phi = y+z) $.

Also, you do not really have $d\phi = -dz $, since the change of variables formula for the Lebesgue integral uses the **absolute value** of the jacobian. Of course, this problem also vanishes if you use the correct substitution from above.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks!